# Passing arguments in jetpack compose navigation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a clickable row that redirects to FoodProducts:

```
.clickable {
                // Navigate to FoodProductsScreen when clicked
                Log.d("Navigation", "Category ID: ${category.id}")

                navController.navigate("${NavGraph.FoodProducts}?categoryId=${category.id}")

            },`
```

When I print the category.id here it logs 2 on the console but when I print it in NavHost it says 0:

```
`        
composable(NavGraph.FoodProducts) { backStackEntry ->
           
            val categoryId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("categoryId") ?: 2
            Log.d("Navigation", "Received Category ID: $categoryId")
            FoodProductsScreen(navController, categoryId)
        }`
```

FoodProductsScreen:

```
`@Composable
fun FoodProductsScreen(navController: NavController, categoryId: Int) {
    val productsInCategory = products.filter { it.id == categoryId }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "${categoryId}")
    }
    LazyColumn {
        items(productsInCategory) { product ->
            FoodProductItem(product = product)
        }
    }
}`
```

I tried a whole lot of things but nothing seems to work...

I tried retrieving the argument from the last view like this:     `FoodProductsScreen(navController, backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("categoryId") ?: 1)`
But it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 val categoryId = navController.currentBackStackEntry
    ?.savedStateHandle?.get<Int>("categoryId") ?: 2
```

Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I think.

```
val myPassedArg = 1
navController.navigate("foodProductsScreenRoute" +"?passedArg=$myPassedArg")
```

And in NavGraph:

```
composable(route = "foodProductsScreenRoute" + "?passedArg={myArg}"){ backStackEntry ->
val defaultValue = 2
val arg = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("myArg")?:defaultValue
FoodProductsScreen(navController = navController,arg)
}
```